# html anchor executes when confirm returns false

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

```
<a href="/user/1/delete" class="delete"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
```

.

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    // Verify deleting objects
    if (e.target.closest(".delete")) {
        return confirm("Are you sure?");
    }
});
```

I am trying to remove jQuery as a dependancy from my code and I am not quite used to JavaScript's event system. I have an `<a>` tag that i want to cancel if confirm returns `false`. However, it still executes when I click `Cancel` on the confirm dialog.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting some more, I found an answer:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    // Verify deleting objects
    if (e.target.closest(".delete")) {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        return;
    }
}
```